# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk' after installation on a Windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04 machine

Tags: permissions, python, anaconda

I've been trying to solve this problem for the last couple of hours, without luck.

I'm trying to run a python program that I wrote on my Windows 10 machine on my other machine that has a dual-boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 "Bionic Beaver", if I recall correctly.

This error comes up everytime I run the code using spyder/pycharm, even after trying a lot of suggestions that I found on here and on stackoverflow:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

So far, I have tried downloading `nltk`:

1) using their own website's instructions: `sudo pip install -U nltk`

2) using anaconda3: `conda install -c anaconda nltk`

First, it used to show me some permission denied problems, because I guess the anaconda3 folder was set to 'access only', but I used: `sudo chown -R usr foldername` to solve that.

I even tried updating `pip`, `anaconda` and `nltk`, without positive results.

Could this be connected to the fact of a dual-boot machine? Or maybe the fact that anaconda is installed?

Weird thing is, when I type `python` in the terminal and then `import nltk` it shows `>>` , and no error message. This is really frustrating and I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: It's probably related to using conda.  I used it for a very short time, and it was easier for me to just blow it out and install things manually.

Comment: @RobotHumans I did just that and it worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably related to using conda. I used it for a very short time, and it was easier for me to just blow it out and install things manually.

*converted from a comment because OP said it solved their problem*